# Network access, routing issue

Tags: routing, gateway

My ISP is providing me 3 IP addresses over a single network cable each assigned to a MAC.
The main network cable is connected to a switch. 2PCs and 1 Router are connected to that switch.

```
PC1 is assigned an IP: 80.16.27.167
PC2 is assigned an IP: 80.16.27.176
Router is assigned an IP: 80.16.27.180

The PC3 is connected to the router having internal IP: 192.168.1.101
```

What I want to do is to be able to access PC1 and PC2 from PC3 directly from my network to transfer files. I'm able to access them via remote desktop.

Actually I was able to do this from my TL-WR1042ND router without any confirguration, but I had to upgrade it to Linksys EA6400 and now I need help to access my network again.

[Security screen on the router:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ykBC.jpg)

[Apps and gaming (port forwarding)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaJiB.jpg)

Comment: Assuming that the WAN port on the router is connected to the 80.16.27.x network and the LAN port is connected to the 192.168.1.x network then the router should already have the required routes in its routing table to route traffic between the two networks. What's probably missing are ACL's on the router allowing traffic between the two networks. What kind of ACL/firewall rules do you have on the router?

Comment: I uploaded an image of the security screen on the router. Check the bottom of main message.

Comment: That's not the right screen. You need to look at the Apps and Gaming screen to see what traffic/services/ports the firewall allows from the WAN to the LAN. Then you need to add the appropriate traffic/services/ports rules for the traffic you want to get to PC3.

Comment: To clarify: Are you initiating communication between the PC's from PC3 or from PC1 and PC2?

Comment: PC1 and PC2 see eachother without problem. I can connect vice versa. The only problem is I can't connect from PC3 which is behind router to PC1 and PC2 which have external IP.
Connection from PC1/PC2 to PC3 is also impossible.

Comment: Can you check the main message for the image of the screen you want.
Than screen is for incoming connections not outgoing. I defined few rules but I think what I need is not there.

Comment: OK. I slightly misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish. When you say that you can't connect from PC3 to PC1/2 what do you mean? How are you trying to connect? What are you trying to do? What messages do you get when trying to connect?

Comment: I mean I don't see them in my network.
When I type \\80.16.27.167 in the address bar of windows explorer I can't access the PC1 to transfer my files.
Error 0x80070035. The network path was not found.